# Is the following singular/plural inconsistency common in informal speech?

Tags: speech

> I saw a white figure inside the house. A ghost? But my uncle had
>   told me they didn't exist.

Is this common in informal English? If not, what's the correct alternative?

Comment: The singular and plural forms of ghosts (plural implied) occur in different sentences, or (reworded) one sentence joined with a conjunction (but).  So there is no grammatical rule/guideline that requires such consistency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really an inconsistency because the first comment is speaking of a specific ghost; the latter refers to ghosts in general. Ex:

"I thought I saw a shark. I'm pretty sure they don't live in lakes, though."

"There's a homeless man sleeping under a garbage pile. Well, that's where they sleep in the winter."

Comment: Exactly. It's very unlikely that the writer's uncle told him that that particular ghost didn't exist.